# how can I generate every combination of key/value from a json array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have a random json array of key,values where the values are arrays like so:

```
json = {foo:[1,2],bar:[3,4],pi:[5]}
```

how can I generate every combination of those parameters for any number of keys so I get back a list like:

```
{foo:1,bar,3,pi:5}
{foo:1,bar:4,pi:5}
{foo:2,bar:3,pi:5}
{foo:2,bar:4,pi:5}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use reduce and for each iteration, generate the new permutations:

```js
const json = {foo:[1,2],bar:[3,4],pi:[5, 7], test: [1]};

const results = Object.keys(json).reduce((acc, key) => {
  const newArray = [];
  
  json[key].forEach(item => {
    if (!acc || !acc.length) { // First iteration
      newArray.push({[key]: item});
    } else {
      acc.forEach(obj => {
        newArray.push({...obj, [key]: item});
      });
    }
  });
  
  return newArray;
}, []);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: I am looking for a version that works for N numbers of keys, I dont know the keys ahead of time. Your example is hardcoded.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: what does the ...obj do? i haven't seen that, when i run in my node code, I get exception on the ... . my node version is v6.11.2

Comment: it will be great if i can find Java version of this version :D